# Per-file executable target for unit tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a rather large Visual Studio solution file containing many project files below it. Each of these projects holds C files and header files along with unit tests, and compiles to an executable or library. Also, each unit test compiles to its own executable.

```
├───Solution
│   ├───project1
|   |   |───some_code.c
|   |   |───more_code.c
│   │   └───unit_tests
|   |       |───test_some_code.c
|   |       |───test_more_code.c
│   │       └───results
|   ├───project2
|   |   |───even_more_code.c
│   │   └───unit_tests
|   |       |───test_even_more_code.c
│   │       └───results
⋱   ⋱
```

Is there a way to configure a corresponding executable for each of these unit tests? I can see the target for the entire project:
[image]
But I don't see a corresponding option for an individual file:
[image]

**[Example Solution folder](http://www.filedropper.com/soexample)**

**Goal: Clicking 'Debug' while viewing any test source code debugs the corresponding unit test executable.**

Comment: Hi, what unit-test framework do you use? I've read it twice but can't really understanding your meaning. Do you want to debug unit test code while debugging project1 core code?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm using CUnit, and the crux of the issue is that I have my CUnit files in the same projects as the code they're covering (so that each project has multiple `main()`s in it. I'm not sure how to debug the unit tests since the project has the non-test code listed in properties as the debuggable executable. I could open project properties and change between source and tests each time I want to switch which executable I'm debugging, but I'm hoping there's a more convenient way.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Could you share a simple sample(after deleting the core code) by github or one-drive so that I can check for your directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, this slipped my mind. I have to be really careful about leaking source, but I've created a new example solution with the same structure, _sans_ code. We might just need to rework our solution and/or unit test setup, so if the example solution doesn't help I'll accept your answer since it's likely to help future SO visitors.

Comment: I've checked your example. Sorry but the goal to debug corresponding unit tests executable while viewing test code is not supported for now in your solution, you may need to create new configuration for test-code-debugging. It may takes some time at the very start when you configure the new configuration, but the development and debug after that would be convenient. Open your .vcxproj file you would find the CICompile Item, you could use [msbuild condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) to control the debug and build behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll investigate the CICompile feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Maybe we can offer a better solution so we don't need to achieve the goal in a way like:`Clicking 'Debug' while viewing any test source code debugs the corresponding unit test.`

In VS IDE, we can configure our new configuration. So you can right-click project=>Configuration Manager or go this way to open the manager:

[image]

In Active solution configurations choose new and set settings like below and click ok:

[image]

After that,for every project in your solution, you can configure their corresponding configuration for debugging unit tests.

**E.g:**

[image]

**Don't forget to configure other related settings in this page like pdb file name.**

When you try to debug project1, set it as startup project, set the configuration to Debug and F5. When trying to debug project1-unit-test, set the configuration to DebugForTest and F5.

[image] Hope it's what you want:)